# how do i find the last six digits of a string using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex, digits

How do I find the last six digits of a string using regex in java?

For instance, I have a string: `238428342938492834823`

I want to have string that finds only the last 6 digits, no matter what the length of the string is. I have tried `"/d{6}$"` with no success.

Any suggestions or new ideas?

Comment: Why on earth would you use regex for that?

Comment: ^Yeah you could do a `string.length()` and then subtract 6 from that..

Comment: @RohitJain he's talking about string not numbers

Comment: @Anirudh. Even I'm talking about strings. `substring` would be the best choice here.

Answer (score 5):

You just used the wrong escape character. `\d{6}` matches six digits, while `/d` matches a literal forward-slash followed by six literal `d`'s.

The pattern should be:

```
\d{6}$
```

Of course, in Java, you also have to escape the `\`, so that:

```
String pattern = "\\d{6}$";
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer provides you with a regex solution to this problem, however regex is not a reasonable solution to the problem.

```
if (text.length >= 6) {
    return text.substring(text.length - 6);
}
```

If you find yourself trying to use regex to solve a problem, the first thing you should do is stop and have a good think about why you think regex is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your String always consists out of just digits, you should consider using a different datatype.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Numberthings {
    static final BigInteger NUMBER_1000000 = BigInteger.valueOf(1000000);
    static final NumberFormat SIX_DIGITS = new DecimalFormat("000000"); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger("238428342938492834823");
        BigInteger result = number.remainder(NUMBER_1000000);
        System.out.println(SIX_DIGITS.format(result.longValue()));

        number = new BigInteger("238428342938492000003");
        result = number.remainder(NUMBER_1000000);
        System.out.println(SIX_DIGITS.format(result.longValue()));
    }
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
834823
000003
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in one line:

```
String last6 = str.replaceAll(".*(.{6})", "$1");
```